# Chartsjs only showing two data points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using charts.js to visualise some data, but unfortunately, I only see two data points, while the scale is like to highest value.

This is my code.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="80"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload=function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
             // The type of chart we want to create
             type: 'line',

             // The data for our dataset
             data: {
                   labels: '',
                   datasets: [{
                          label: 'Tests',
                          backgroundColor: 'rgb(252, 160, 12)',
                          borderColor: 'rgb(8, 19, 42)',
                          data: [
                           {x:'2016-12-23', y:200}, {x:'2016-12-24', y:300}, {x:'2016-12-25', y:400}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:100}
                                            ]
                          }]
                  },

                  // Configuration options go here
                  options: {
                            legend: {
                                    display: false
                                    },
                            }
                       });
                 };

       </script>
```

I don't see, why this is limited. Suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: It is working fine although you might want to remove the labels options since you specify your data as an object https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/n8m9kgb6/1/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was actually using an old version as I was calling 2.8 which didn't support this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, please.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="80"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload=function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
             // The type of chart we want to create
             type: 'line',

             // The data for our dataset
             data: {
                   labels: ['2016-12-23','2016-12-24','2016-12-25','2016-12-26']
                   datasets: [{
                          label: 'Tests',
                          backgroundColor: 'rgb(252, 160, 12)',
                          borderColor: 'rgb(8, 19, 42)',
                          data: [200, 300, 400 100]
                          }]
                  },

                  // Configuration options go here
                  options: {
                            legend: {
                                    display: false
                                    },
                            }
                       });
                 };

       </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, as I need the data to be an object.

Comment: What do you mean? what do you want to see on the line?

Comment: It's about how I can put the data into the js part.